# Subsequence converging to supremum of sequence

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(a_n)$ be a bounded sequence of reals satisfying
>   $$a_n<L:=\sup\{a_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that there exists a subsequence $a_{n_j}$ that converges to $L$.

I was thinking of constructing a sequence such that $L-\frac{1}{n}<a_{n_j}<L$, but how do we know that there exist elements of $a_n$ such that $L-1\in a_n$ for example?

*There is a theorem in my analysis textbook that says:
A sequence $(s_n)$ has a subsequence converging to $t$ if and only if the set $\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid |a_n-t|<\varepsilon\}$ is infinite for all $\varepsilon>0$.*

Could someone provide a proof using this theorem?

Comment: Build the sequence recursively.  Start with $a_1$ and show that there must be some $a_i$ with $a_1<a_i<L$,  Continue in that way.

Comment: Or start immediately by assuming that such a subsequence does not exist.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry, I happened to stumble on this sometime back and noticed something big. I believe that what you meant to write in the theorem is the limit superior, denoted by $lim sup_{n \rightarrow ∞}$ instead of just $sup$ which means supremum. Here's a simple contradiction to your claim: take any monitonically strictly decreasing sequence which is bounded. Clearly, it converges to a value, and we know that all sunquences of the sequnce will also converge to that point. But the supremum of the sequence will be the first term itself, and clearly no subsequence converges to the $sup$.

Comment: Also, another thing is that if the theorem that your analysis book claims is true, and that is indeed what you meant is limit superior then there is no need to prove too much; what its basically saying is that if and only if $t$ is a limit point, then there exists a subsequence that converges to it. Is the sequence is bounded the $lim sup$ will be finite and hence a limit point (a very easy theorem to prove). Since it is a limit point, there exists a subsequnce which converges to the value.

Comment: @PratikApshinge in the example you give the first term would however be **equal** to the supremum. Thus this sequences does not fulfill the condition. It is crucial that the inequality is strict. With $\le$ instead of $<$ the claim is indeed false, and your example would show it.

Comment: Thank you... That makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No $M<L$ is an upper bound for the set $A=\{a_n:n\in \Bbb N\}.$

Let $n_1=1.$  For $j\in \Bbb N,$ define $n_{j+1}$ recursively as follows:

For brevity let $V(j)=\max \{a_k:1\leq k\leq n_j\}.$ We have $V(j)<L.$

Let $M(j)=\max (L-2^{-j},V(j)).$ Then $M(j)<L$ so $M(j)$ is not an upper bound for $A.$ So let $n_{j+1}$ be the least (or any) $n$ such that $a_n>M(j).$

We have $n_{j+1}>n_j$ because  if $k\leq n_j$ we have $a_k\leq V(j)\leq M(j)<a_{n_{j+1}},$ implying $k\ne n_{j+1}.$

Conclusion: The sequence $(a_{n_j})_{j\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $L$ because we have $L-2^{-j}\leq M(j)< a_{n_{j+1}}<L.$

Remark: The reason this will not work if we replaced $L$ with some $L'>L$ is that for some (large enough) $j$ we would have $M(j)\geq L'-2^{-j}>\sup A,$ whereupon $n_{j+1}$ won't exist.

Comment: I don't understand the part from 'we have' to 'implying'? Could you clarify this part please?

Comment: $a_{n_{j+1}}$ is greater than every member of $\{a_k: k\leq n_j\}$ so $a_{n_{j+1}}$  is not a member of $ \{a_k: k\leq n_j\}$ so the index $n_{j+1}$  cannot be equal to any member of $\{k:k\leq n_j\} $.

Comment: could you clarify why you take the maximum of $L-2^{-j}$ and $V(j)$?

Comment: First, $a_{n_{j+1}}>L-2^{-j}$  ensures  that $a_{n_j}\to L $ as $ j\to \infty.$ Second,  $a_{n_{j+1}}>V(j)$  ensures that  $n_{j+1}>n_j$.

Comment: You are great, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a few years on, but I love this question and have been pondering over it a while. 
Let the sequence be ${(a_n)}_{n=m}^{∞}$
Now $L:=sup\{a_n| n \in \mathbb N\}$.
Take any $\epsilon>0$ which is real. 
Then, by the definition of a supremum, there will exist an $n$ such that $a_n>L-\epsilon$.
Let this $n=n^*$
For this very $n^*$, $a_{n^*}<L+\epsilon$.
Therefore for that $n^*$, $|a_{n^*} - L|<\epsilon$.

Now, suppose that for an N≥m, the sequence ${(a_n)}_{n=N}^{∞}$ has no term that is greater than $L-\epsilon$. Then, the sequence ${(a_n)}_{n=m}^{N}$ is finite and has a term which is equal to the least upper bound or supremum. But this contradicts the fact that the supremum is strictly greater than $a_n$ for all $n$. Hence, for every $N≥m$, you can always find an n such that $a_n>L-\epsilon$.

This proves, for every $N≥m$ and every real $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $n≥N$, such that  $|a_n - L|<\epsilon$.(1)

Now we know, "a sequence $(s_n)$ has a subsequence converging to $t$ if and only if the set $\{n\in \mathbb N∣ |a_n−t|<\epsilon\}$ is infinite for all $\epsilon>0$." [This is the defintion of a limit point]

By (1), this set will be infinite for this sequence and thus, there will exist a subsequence which converges to $L$.